# Pervasive Date Comparison

Tags: sql, pervasive, pervasive-sql

I am a newbie to Pervasive and I am trying to fetch  all records from Patient table where the Date of birth of Patient is not '11/30/0002'

The Birthdate is stored in MM/DD/YYYY format in the system

Requesting your assistance

Comment: Date of birth of patient is of String type or Date type?

Comment: Regardless of the datatype of the column, `where dob <> '11/30/0002'` should work.

Answer (score 2):

If the field is defined as a `date`, then you can use the standard format to restrict the data.  For example:

```
select * from Patient where birthdate <> '0002-11-30'
```

The date format `YYYY-MM-DD`. If it's not in that format, you can convert it using various functions.  For example:

```
select right('06/05/1995',4) + '-'  + substring('06/05/1995',4,2) + '-' + left('06/05/1995', 2)
```